# How to set the default working directory in VS2022 for ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

In VS2022 I created a brand new ASP.NET Core Web API. I am launching it via IISExpress.

In `program.cs` I have added these lines of code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        Console.WriteLine(currentDirectory);

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

The current working directory is always the project directory, whereas I am expecting the output directory there. I tried to set my working directory in `launchsettings.json` - without effect.

In VS2019 this was working as expected.

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Could you use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location for this purpose? That should point to your bin folder.

Comment: I can, but thats not the point. The default (current) directory should be the same in dev mode and runtime mode, but it isnt.